# Wrong web page horizontal scroll messing up layout

Tags: css, layout, scroll, width, horizontal-scrolling

For the following site: http://mountainfoodstorage.com, when the window is maximized (wider than about 1520px), the page displays correctly. But if the window is thinner than about 1520px, a horizontal scrollbar appears, and if I scroll to the right, my layout appears messed up (divs that are supposed to span the whole width are cut off). The content of my web page is only about 1000px wide, so the horizontal scrollbar is kicking in about 500 pixels too early. I've inspected the page's elements to see if anything is bumping up the width to around 1520px, but I can't find anything that's doing this. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem seems to be somewhere inside of the "main-menu-container" div.  When I tell that div to go to `display:none`, the horizontal scroll bar goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's the `#main-menu`, width + left = 1250 instead of your site width.  Remove the `left` style and add `float:right` to the `ul`

```
#main-menu {
    position:relative;
    left:265px; /* remove this */
    width:985px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

#main-menu ul {
    margin-left:0;
    float: right; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved most of the problem. I'm still getting about 75px of unwanted scroll space. It's probably a similar problem with another element. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Fully fixed. My other problem was that that my horizontally stacked container divs were of varying widths.

Answer (score 0):

Add `html, body {overflow-x: hidden;}`?

Comment: Ya, he can do that as the quick fix, or actually figure out which box is overflowing and not scaling.  I did quit looking when i saw min-height set in pixels.  I recommend to OP to look at responsive website design and the box model to solve the problem.